# Is there a difference between "git merge" and "git checkout -b"?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-checkout

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

I would like to confirm that at the end of the "Pushing" section on the above page,

(1) Execute `git merge origin/serverfix` after fetch

(2) Run `git checkout -b serverfix origin/serverfix`

Am I correct in understanding that operation (1) and (2) have the same effect after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference; no, they don't have the same effect.

As the linked document explains, `git merge origin/serverfix` will merge the remote branch "origin/serverfix" with whichever branch is currently checked out (the current working branch), while `git checkout -b origin/serverfix` will create a *new* local branch named "serverfix" based on the remote "origin/serverfix" and then check out the new branch.

Comment: @森口万太郎: note that [comments](/help/privileges/comment) should only address specific things, and "thank you" comments are discouraged. Instead, if someone provides a useful [answer](/help/someone-answers), you can upvote it. If one answer resolves your issue, you can [accept](/help/accepted-answer) it. Please read through the [help] for more information on how SO operates.

Answer (score 3):

- `git checkout -b` creates a different branch and switches you to it. `git checkout -b serverfix origin/serverfix` specifies that the new local branch `serverfix` should point to the same commit as the `serverfix` of the `origin` remote.
- `git merge` merges changes from the specified commit into your current branch, updating your current branch.

They’re completely different. You’ll be on different branches after executing them, and may not even have the same `HEAD` content.

Answer (score 1):

The order is important:

First you create a topic branch. Since [Git 2.23 (Q3 2019)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309), the right command would be [git switch -c](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch):

```
git switch -c serverfix
```

Since `git switch` has (like `git checkout` before) a [guess mode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---guess), this is equivalent to:

```
git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

The other command is to merge back the topic branch work to your current branch.
If that current branch was your own version of `serverfix`, a simple `git pull` would be enough (short for "`git fetch` + `git merge origin/serverfix`")

But if you want to directly merge a remote branch to your current branch:

```
git fetch
git switch main
git merge origin/serverfix
```